# Compile Elsevier template get this error: LaTeX3 Error: The key 'stm/author/<options>' is unknown and is being(LaTeX3) ignored

Tags: compiling, templates, compilation-error, els-cas

I download Elsevier template here https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/, and use `cas-dc-template.tex`, when I compile it, I get this error:

> LaTeX3 Error: The key 'stm/author/' is unknown and is being(LaTeX3) ignored. \author[]{}[]

I use TexLive and TeXstudio 3.1.2.
Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: you can't use the template unchanged. You will have to replace various placeholders (eg. `<options>` ) first by real values.

Comment: I think you are right, I will try it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment above, the author of the example file has made a poor choice in using `< >` as placeholders, as they prevent the example file from compiling.

Replace all of the things in angle brackets like `<author>` with, e.g., `Author` and the file will compile.